# Problem with HP mini 1104 wifi card in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, hp

I have a HP mini 1104 with windows 7 installed by default. When I install Ubuntu 12.04 and try to activate the proprietary drivers, I only see the graphics card.

When you connect to the wifi wireless card is turned off and intermittently, if it detects networks but does not have a stable connection.

My network card is a Ralink RT3593

Does anyone know the solution to my problem?

Comment: English please..

Comment: Tyr connecting Laptop(?) tot eh ethernet cable and see if you can download drivers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.Specifically, can you add the output of `sudo lshw -class network` and either `lsusb` or `lspci`

Comment: This may also require blacklisting the **rt2800** driver, which (by default) attempts to control **rt3593**. See: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2091535 (open) and http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/rt2800pci

Comment: my computer is this [link](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF06a/321957-321957-64295-3841267-3955550-5160433.html?dnr=1) attempt to install the broadcom driver but did not work

Comment: *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Ralink corp.
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 9c:b7:0d:5e:c9:2e
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.2.0-23-generic firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:82000000-8200ffff